# Angular - Typescript filter em array

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

Tenho um json das cidades brasileiras.

Para obter todas as cidades do estado que exista no ARRAY idEstado com ÚNICO item, faço da seguinte forma:

```
getCidades(idEstado: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Cidade[]>('assets/dados/cidades.json')
      .pipe(
        map((cidades: Cidade[]) => cidades.filter(c => c.estado == idEstado))
      );
}
```

Este código não funciona se eu tiver mais de um estado no ARRAY idEstado.

Como fazer para que me seja retornado as cidades de todos os estados que estejam no array?

Comment: Provavelmente utilizando `map((cidades: Cidade[]) => cidades.filter(c => Array.isArray(idEstado) ? idEstado.includes(c.estado) : idEstado == c.estado))`, mas essa pergunta está longe de ser clara.

Comment: Perfeito! Era isto mesmo que eu procurava. Funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado e me desculpe pela falta de clareza na pergunta, oportunamente procurarei melhorar.

Answer (score 0):

Para fins de registro e, quem sabe, ser útil a outros, segue a solução conforme resposta do [user140808](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/140828/user140828)

```
  getCidades(idEstado: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Cidade[]>('assets/dados/cidades.json')
      .pipe(
        map((cidades: Cidade[]) => cidades.filter(c => Array.isArray(idEstado) ? idEstado.includes(c.estado) : idEstado == c.estado))
      );
  }
```

Desta forma, são retornadas todas as cidades cujos estados estejam no array idEstado.